# we are fail to receive an user’s email data 1 in every 30 to 50 participants

Tags: email, facebook-fql

Following is the code sources that loading the Facebook user’s email after the approval of the APP.
There is the problem that we are fail to receive an user’s email data 1 in every 30 to 50 participants.
Could you please check the code sources for us to solve this problem?

```
// FQL Call
$fql = "SELECT email, name from user where uid = ".$facebook_id;
$profile = $facebook->api(array(
           "method" => "fql.query",
           "query" => $fql,
));

$name = $profile[0]["name"];
$email = $profile[0]["email"];

// Registration
$query = "INSERT INTO `facebook_data` (`name`, `email`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."');";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could this be searching through users that have removed the app or changed their permissions after adding it?

Comment: not answering your question, but you should definitely sanitize $name and $email before running that insert statement, or bobby tables will be your friend

Comment: User's "Name" data will be received without a problem.

Comment: yes, but if that Name happens to contain special characters like "george o'malley" your sql statement will be broken